# io-streams partitionEithers

Tags: haskell, stream

I have a worker function

```
worker :: a -> Either b c
```

and I want to apply it to a stream of `a` and produce 2 streams of `b` and `c` and process those streams further. For example, I want to accumulate `c` in a `Map` (essentially to fold the stream) and output `b` to `stderr`.

How can I achieve this with `io-streams`? It seems I cannot call `connect` twice. So I have to put it before the partitioning, so the partitioning will operate on `OutputStream` in a "contravariant" way:

```
contrapartitionEithers
  :: OutputStream b -> OutputStream c -> IO (OutputStream (Either b c))
```

Is it implementable? If no, how can do the task at hand? If yes, is is somehow "dual" to `System.IO.Streams.zip`?

```
System.IO.Streams.zip
  :: InputStream a -> InputStream b -> IO (InputStream (a, b))
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the right question contains the answer. So it's possible indeed:

```
contrapartitionEithers
  :: OutputStream b -> OutputStream c -> IO (OutputStream (Either b c))
contrapartitionEithers b c = makeOutputStream $ maybe
     (writeTo b Nothing >> writeTo c Nothing)
     (either (writeTo b . Just) (writeTo c . Just))
```